# How to pass request body as a form-data in apex oracle Rest Data Source?

Tags: oracle-apex, form-data, lowcode, restdatasource

[image]

I have one API in that I am using post method and I am passing one request body as form data. It was working in my postman but in apex low code rest data source it was not working and not getting the request body why?

How to pass the request body as form data?

Comment: Can you share an example on how the actual request body should look like? No Postman UI please, I'd like to see which actual request body is expected.

Comment: @Carsten
The Request body look like this.
 data_code:592

Comment: Can you share a "curl" request example, so that I can see all the request details?

Comment: (Postman has an "export to cURL" function; which you can use.